# How To center Vaadin grid header and compared to its colum row?

Tags: vaadin-grid

I want to center both table header and its column row inside Vaadin Grid..

I run this HashMapWithGridAndBinder example (https://cookbook.vaadin.com/grid-with-map).

And it is how it looks. [image]

How to set the colum header to be centered compared its colum row content?

many thanks.
vaadin-flow 24

Answer (score 0):

```
 grid.addColumn(map -> map.get(key))
         ...
         .setHeader(key)
         **.setTextAlign(ColumnTextAlign.CENTER);**
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**